# To make Gluten free pancakes, can I just substitute regular flour with Gluten free flour?

Tags: substitutions, pancakes, gluten-free, quickbread

Will a normal pancake recipe work with Gluten free flour, or do I need to add other ingredients as well?

Comment: @Aaronut Why the tag "quickbread"? It's not a food term relating to pancakes?

Comment: @TFD: Sure it is. Pancakes are a type of quickbread, and this question is equally applicable to many if not most other quickbreads (waffles, muffins, etc.)

Comment: @Aaronut North American term, not in Oxford dictionary... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by gluten-free flour. If you are buying a gluten-free flour mix that it labeled for all-purpose use then you should be able to substitute that and get a reasonably good result. Substituting straight rice or almond flour in a standard recipe will not work well, because the mixes have a blend of ingredients designed to make it perform similar to flour.

It may take some recipe/flour experimentation to get it as close to what you are used to, but will definetly make something edible. There are also various almond-flour based pancake recipes which work well.